# regex for finding a comma OR a new line

Tags: regex, csv, delimiter

I'm parsing a CSV file and I wanted to use the `useDelimiter(",")` as well as `useDelimiter("\n")`.
I think I can do this using regex to find all instances of commas OR new lines.

Does someone know how I might do this using a `useDelimiter()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK:
got it:
    `useDelimiter(",|\\\n");`

the `|` is the OR and the double backslashes `\\` or an escape clause allowing us to use the new line character `\n`